# load a file in u-boot over nfs

Tags: nfs, u-boot

Note: this is not about using nfs for the rootfs or using tftp to download a kernel.

U-boot is based on `v2017.11`, the board is custom but similar to the imx6dl-sabresd.

I've set `CONFIG_CMD_NFS=y` in `.config`.  I have a working nfs server on an Arch Linux host.  I can mount the nfs share as my rootfs.

My nfs share is at `/srv/nfs/foo`, and `/etc/exports.d/foo.exports` looks like

```
/srv/nfs/foo *(rw,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

When I try to do e.g. `nfs $loadaddr $nfsroot/boot/zImage`, it just keeps printing `T` for timeout.  (`nfsroot=/srv/nfs/foo` to match the export.)  The file exists on the share and the network is working (`ping $serverip` works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to enable udp on the nfs server.  On Arch Linux, this is in `/etc/nfs.conf`:

```
[nfsd]
udp=y
```

I don't have any other customization (other than exports).

Looking into this it seems like newer versions of nfs (for reference, I'm using `nfs-utils` 2.3.1) disable udp by default, but apparently u-boot needs udp support.

Comment: Correct, at this point in time we do not support TCP for NFS, only UDP, so you must have that enabled on the server.